# How to update one table based on the data of an other table?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, toad, sql-function

I have the following 2 tables in mySQL. I would like to update `table_1` with the data of `table_2` if that data is not present in `table_1` or if the data has changed.

These are my tables:

```
table_1:

id    name    desc     price 
------------------------------
1     a       audi        100
2     b       bmw         221
3     c       mercedes    331 

table_2:

id    name    desc      price
------------------------------
1     a       audi         1200
2     b       bmw          250
3     c       mercedes     500
4     d       opel         400
5     e       volkswagen   340
```

**My desired output would be:**

```
table_1

id    name    desc      price
------------------------------
1     a       audi         1200
2     b       bmw          250
3     c       mercedes     500
4     d       opel         400
5     e       volkswagen   340
```

**This is what I tried:**

```
UPDATE table_1
   SET (name, desc) = (SELECT table_2.name, table_2.desc
                         FROM table_2 t2
                        WHERE table_1.id = table_2.id)
 WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
      FROM table_2
     WHERE table_1.id = table_2.id )
```

**This is what I got:**

```
Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(name, desc) = (SELECT table_2.name, table_2.desc                          FROM ' at line 2    0.000 sec
```

**Please note that my tables are much bigger in reality. PS I'am using Toad.

Comment: Deleteing table1 and renaming table2 is an option, but I'm not a fan of deleting data that fast, afraid this might have a effect on the whole proces. `table_1` is used in different programs, afraid that link might go astray.

Comment: @RiggsFolly did you just delete your 1st comment?

Comment: Yes, i thought it might be considered a little facetious

Comment: Another question might be which column can you GUARANTEE is unique on both tables and WILL NOT ever get changed. So you can us that to match the rows on the 2 tables

Comment: Well... can this be solved using an sql function? column1s unique. the ID

Comment: @RiggsFolly Can you show how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the INSERT on DUPLICATE mechanism would do this in one quite consise query

```
INSERT INTO table_1 (`id`, `name`,`desc`,`price`)
    (
     SELECT `t2`.`id`, `t2`.`name`, `t2`.`desc`, `t2`.`price` 
     from table_2 t2 
     where id = t2.id
    )
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `name`=`t2`.`name`, 
                        `desc`=`t2`.`desc`, 
                        `price`=`t2`.`price`;
```

Comment: it says `Error Code 1054 Unknown column id in field list`. How is that possible? I literaraly have the same column name as you

Comment: @Im trying it out on MySQL Workbench 8.0

Comment: Ah excuse me, I got it working. My tables are named `table_1` and `table_2` instead of `table1` and `table2`. Thank you. I guess I can now manually delete `table_2` ?

Comment: My fault, I should stick to the names used in the question, sorry

Comment: No problem. Just 1 more question. Why are you using t2? Where does it stand for?

Comment: Thats an alias for table_2, just a short hand, makes the code easier to write and read

Comment: See this bit of the code `from table_2 t2` is could be written as `from table_2 AS t2`